# Parsing xdocument and binding to grid

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, linq-to-xml

I am having tought time to bind a xdocument data to a gridview. I need help on this thought I tried various ways to do the same but all in vain..... Below is the xml string .

```
    <sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"> 
    <head>  
    <variable name="EmpId" />    <variable name="EmpName" />    </head>
    <results> 
    <result> <binding name="EmpId">  
    <uri>http://www.brightstardb.com/categories/1</uri>    </binding>
    <binding name="EmpName">  
    <uri>http://www.brightstardb.com/categories/Smith</uri>    </binding> 
    </result> <result> </results> </sparql>
```

I need to bind this to a gridview in dotnet c# win application, below is one approach I took but couldn't succeed to bind.......Pls help.

```
 var result = XDocument.Load(client.ExecuteQuery(storeName, query));
var doc = XDocument.Parse(result.ToString());
IEnumerable<Prescriber> products = from x in doc.Descendants("result")
     select new Prescriber()
      {
               EmpId= x.Element("EmpId").Value,
               EmpName= x.Element("EmpName").Value
       };
```

Comment: Please add your original XML to the question, not as a comment. As a first step please be aware of XML namespace, your query should include too like doc.Descendants(ns+"result"), where XNamespace ns = "w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";

Comment: Well I have put original XML but the preview has parsed that can anyone please let me know if xml has to put in code/comment block.

Comment: Easiest way: copy+paste xml to the editor, then select your xml content with mouse and click on "Code sample" button "{}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea that you wanted two columns in the datagrid, "EmpId" and "EmpName". With the given XML, i expected one row, the first column is = "http://www.brightstardb.com/categories/1" and the second is = "http://www.brightstardb.com/categories/Smith"

If it is true, here is a sample code:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#";

    var products = from x in doc.Descendants(ns + "result")
                 select new Prescriber
                 {
                     EmpId = x.Elements(ns + "binding").Single(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "EmpId").Element(ns + "uri").Value,
                     EmpName = x.Elements(ns + "binding").Single(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "EmpName").Element(ns + "uri").Value
                 };

    datagridview.DataSource = products.ToList();
```

Be careful about the following:

Sample will fail if "EmpId" or "EmpName" attribute is missing for any of the "result" XElement.

Prescriber class needs real properties " public string EmpId { get; set; } " simple field won't work.

You have to call .ToList() as a last step, for some reason IEnumerable< T > won't work.

And yes, a LinqToXML query is a bit more complex and look for MSDN if you have time.

Comment: xeondev, Thanks and appricate your time and help, this has resolved my issue.